# Simple lapply task

Tags: r, lapply

I have a question regarding using lapply. For example, consider a very very simple example.

```
dir = list("2013", "2012", "2011")
```

And I want to use lapply to transform these elements into something like "year_2013", "year_2012", and "year_2011". How would I do that? I've tried something like

```
dir = lapply(dir, paste0("year", dir))
```

But that doesn't quite work.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: The second argument to `lapply` must be a function. In your case: `lapply(dir,function(x) paste0("year",x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sapply` to get a vector

```
> sapply(dir, function(x) paste("year", x, sep="_"))
[1] "year_2013" "year_2012" "year_2011"
```

Use `lapply` to get a list

```
> lapply(dir, function(x) paste("year", x, sep="_"))
[[1]]
[1] "year_2013"

[[2]]
[1] "year_2012"

[[3]]
[1] "year_2011"
```

Answer (score 5):

Why do you want to use lapply? Simply use:

```
> paste0('year_',dir)
[1] "year_2013" "year_2012" "year_2011"
```